# Sync offline data in react progressive web app from indexeddb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

Hi I am creating a progressive web app with react and redux I have converted it to the progressive web app and now I am also storing the data into indexeddb to but I am having trouble syncing offline data.

I have implemented this approach in my App component I listening for online and offline events of the browser then I am syncing the offline data.
Here is my code.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('offline',() => {
      this.syncOfflineData()
    });
    window.removeEventListener('online',() => {
      this.syncOfflineData()
    });
  }

  syncOfflineData = () => {
    console.log('a ajax request to sync offline data')

  }
```

The **syncOfflineData  function** is working but i am having trouble with it for example if i have same page open in multiple tabs for examples 4 tabs then it will run syncOfflineData function 4 times due to 4 open tabs so it is adding the same record 4 times in database due to sending ajax request 4 times 1 for each tab.
I have also tried adding a unique value from client side but the **syncOfflineData function** runs at the same time when it connects to internet so it means 4 ajax requests are sent to the server at the same time due to that my client unique values are not found in database so it inserts 4 same records in database.

Can anyone let me know Is their a way for me to sync correctly like no matter how many tabs are open it sends only requests not each same request for each new tab when it connects or disconnects to interent.

kindly help me with this.

Comment: Why do you need to open it in multiple tabs? Do you have an identifier? Let's say you have something that makes the user or even the device uniquely identifiable and then if requests come in to the backend you block them per identifier / let surpass only one request?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If you have a website then the user can open that websites in multiple tabs it's user choice to open the websites in how many tabs he wants.
About the unique identifier, I am generating a unique key using javascript for each record and I am checking that key before putting the record in the database but it is not working because all of the requests are sent parallel so they execute at the same time so the unique key does not found in database.

Comment: @p0rter that is the main issue i am facing if you can please help with this then it will be great.Thanks in advance.